# Find array item in a string

Tags: python, arrays, string, find, match

I know can use `string.find()` to find a substring in a string.

But what is the easiest way to find out if one of the array items has a substring match in a string without using a loop?

Pseudocode:

```
string = 'I would like an apple.'
search = ['apple','orange', 'banana']
string.find(search) # == True
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use a generator expression (which somehow *is* a loop)

```
any(x in string for x in search)
```

The generator expression is the part inside the parentheses. It creates an iterable that returns the value of `x in string` for each `x` in the tuple `search`. `x in string` in turn returns whether `string` contains the substring `x`. Finally, the Python built-in [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) iterates over the iterable it gets passed and returns if any of its items evaluate to `True`.

Alternatively, you could use a regular expression to avoid the loop:

```
import re
re.search("|".join(search), string)
```

I would go for the first solution, since regular expressions have pitfalls (escaping etc.).

Comment: +1 for generator expression. -1 for regex. +1 for recommending against regex. Huzzah! +1!

Comment: @nmichaels: I included the regex example only because of the "no loop" requirement.

Comment: @Sven: I figured. My tongue was pretty firmly in cheek there; this is a solid answer.

Comment: @Sven Marnach To cut the possible symbolic meaning of some characters in **search** , according to the rules of re, it can be done: ``re.search("|".join(re.escape(search)), string)`` What other pitfall then remain ?

Comment: @eyquem: In this particular example, escaping might be the only pitfall.

Comment: @Sven Marnach OK. BTW I upvote for having given the simpler answer AND having evoked a regex.

Answer (score 3):

Strings in Python are sequences, and you can do a quick membership test by just asking if one string exists inside of another:

```
>>> mystr = "I'd like an apple"
>>> 'apple' in mystr
True
```

Sven got it right in his first answer above. To check if any of several strings exist in some other string, you'd do:

```
>>> ls = ['apple', 'orange']
>>> any(x in mystr for x in ls)
True
```

Worth noting for future reference is that the built-in 'all()' function would return true only if *all* items in 'ls' were members of 'mystr':

```
>>> ls = ['apple', 'orange']
>>> all(x in mystr for x in ls)
False
>>> ls = ['apple', 'like']
>>> all(x in mystr for x in ls)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

The simpler is

```
import re
regx = re.compile('[ ,;:!?.:]')

string = 'I would like an apple.'
search = ['apple','orange', 'banana']

print any(x in regx.split(string) for x in search)
```

EDIT

Correction, after having read Sven's answer: evidently, **string** has to not be splited, stupid ! `any(x in string for x in search)` works pretty well

If you want no loop:

```
import re
regx = re.compile('[ ,;:!?.:]')

string = 'I would like an apple.'
search = ['apple','orange', 'banana']
print regx.split(string)

print set(regx.split(string)) & set(search)
```

result

```
set(['apple'])
```